# Probability problem. Is it right?

Tags: statistics

The prob to pass math is .80, english .70 and both .60.
Find prob of passing one or the other

Answer?
$$
d(a \cup b)=d(a)+d(b)-d(a \cap b) = 0.8+0.7-0.6 = 0.9
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that’s right, apart from the typo: presumably you meant to write

$$P(a\cup b)=P(a)+P(b)\color{red}{-}P(a\cap b)\;,$$

to match the calculation $0.8+0.7-0.6(=0.9)$.

Comment: yes thats what i meant :) thank you.

Comment: @spiros: You’re welcome.

Comment: I suppose a $d$ does look like a $P$ rotated by $180$ degrees $\ldots$

Comment: @Dilip: Second nature, if one’s ever taught frieze patterns in liberal arts math. :-)